# Get records GROUPing BY and discarding duplicates

Tags: mysql

I have a "transaction_status" table:

```
id  transaction_id  status
1         12           0
2         13           0
3         12          -1
4         14           0
5         13          -1
6         15           0
[END OF TABLE]
```

I need to get the transaction ids which only have a record with status=0.

For example this is what I am looking for from the above table:

```
id   transaction_id   status
4          14            0
6          15            0
```

So far I am trying:

```
SELECT id, transaction_id, status  
FROM transaction_status
WHERE status = 0 OR status = -1
ORDER BY status ASC
GROUP BY txn_id
HAVING status = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made a small change in the having clause.

```
SELECT id, transaction_id, status  
FROM transaction_status
WHERE status = 0 OR status = -1
GROUP BY transaction_id
HAVING min(status) = 0
```

I also removed `order by` as it does not make any sense

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Just realised the order by used in between. Corrected

Comment: It works! but could I order the results by id DESC? I put `ORDER BY id` before and after the `GROUP BY` but it does not work. Please help

Comment: @karlosuccess Add order by after having

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP BY` and in `having` clause check for both `min` and `max` status is `0`.

**Query**

```
select  `transaction_id`
from `your_table_name`
group by`transaction_id`
having min(`status`) = 0 and max(`status`) = 0;
```

Comment: This is great. It is working! How could I order the results by id ASC? I put ORDER BY id before and after the GROUP BY but it does not work. Any thought please???

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to handle this is to use conditional aggregation by `transaction_id` and count which IDs have only a status of 0 associated with them.  Do this in a subquery, and then join back to your main table to retrieve the full matching records which you want.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM transaction_status t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT transaction_id
    FROM transaction_status
    GROUP BY transaction_id
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN status <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
) t2
    ON t1.transaction_id = t2.transaction_id
ORDER BY t1.id DESC
```